# retain the checked value in GET

Tags: php

i have the codes that retain the value after post back. i also want to retain the value using GET. example i have ( example.php?id) i want to retain the value using $_GET['id'] what method should i do .

```
 if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['sym1']) && in_array($condition1,$_POST['sym1']))
            $strIsChecked='checked="checked"';
        else
            $strIsChecked=null;

                 echo '<br><input type="checkbox" '.$strIsChecked.' title ="'.$otherspec1.'" name="sym1[]"  onclick="javascript: submit()" value ="'.$condition1.'">';   echo ''.$condition1.'</td>';
```

Comment: I have read this question 3 times and I still do NOT understand what you're trying to say..

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Any error?

Comment: im trying to say is i have a code of retaining checked value in postback, i also want using GET method to retain the checked value

Comment: i still dont have i just did not know what approach im going to do

Comment: I too am not clear on what you are asking?

Comment: If you're getting all checked value in POST, why are asking them to be in GET? I have a scenario, what you want to say... After submitting form, you're getting POST values but not the GET value (i.e. id) and you need that value after submitting form, right?

Comment: because i`am using imagemapping after i click the part the value i got checked is going to uncheck all. i want after clicking the imagemap with is goiing to example.php?id will also return all checked value

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
// this is suppose to replace your If(...)..  
$sym1 = isset($_REQUEST["sym1"]) ? $_REQUEST["sym1"] : '';
$strIsChecked = in_array($sym1, array('option1', 'option2')) ? 'checked="checked"' : null;
echo '<br><input type="checkbox" '.$strIsChecked.' title ="'.$otherspec1.'" name="sym1[]"  onclick="javascript: submit()" value ="'.$condition1.'">';
echo ''.$condition1.'</td>';

// your code with modification  .....
if(isset($_REQUEST) && isset($_REQUEST['sym1']) && in_array($condition1,$_POST['sym1']))
    $strIsChecked='checked="checked"';
else
    $strIsChecked=null;

echo '<br><input type="checkbox" '.$strIsChecked.' title ="'.$otherspec1.'" name="sym1[]"  onclick="javascript: submit()" value ="'.$condition1.'">';   echo ''.$condition1.'</td>';
```

Comment: where should i put that? and is that a correct syntax?

Comment: bro can you construct it with my code above ididint know where should i put that sorry